# I am trying to perform a simple crud operation findall() using spring boot, it complies without any errors or warnings but give a NULL exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, crud-repository

this is a part of TopicService.java

I get a NULL pointer exception at this line
TopicRepo.findAll().forEach(topics::add);

private topicRepo TopicRepo; this is where I am auto wiring the dependency

```
package io.javabrains.example.topic;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


@Service
public class TopicService {// creating a business service

    @Autowired
    private topicRepo TopicRepo; // whenever the TopicService creates an instance then the instance of topicRepo will be injectjed in the variable

    private ArrayList<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Topic("spring1", "nishhcal", "name"),
                new Topic("spring2", "nishhca2", "name2"),
                new Topic("spring3", "nishhca3", "name3")));



    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){

//        return topics;
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        TopicRepo.findAll().forEach(topics::add);
        return topics;
    }

    public Topic getSpecificTopic(String id){
//        for (int r=0; r < topics.size(); r++){
//
//            if((topics.get(r).getId()).equals(id)){
//
//                return topics.get(r);
//            }
//        }
//        return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();// alternative way of doing it
        return topics.get(0);
    }

    public void addTopic(Topic topic){
//        topics.add(topic);
        TopicRepo.save(topic);

    }
```

topicRepo.java, this is where I am extending the crud repository

```
package io.javabrains.example.topic;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface topicRepo extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {

}
```

and this is what is have in my application.properties file

```
#JPA
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

here is a part of my Topic.java

```
package io.javabrains.example.topic;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;


    public Topic() {

    }
```

Comment: Let me guess you are doing `new TopicService()` and still expect it to be auto wired.

Answer (score 0):

Is Topic class annotated with JPA @Entity and have @Id on String field ?
Note: Try to declare Class/Interface names in Capitalized format.

Comment: I've included the Topic.java up there, still getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

Add @Repository annotation in your topicRepo interface :

```
@Repository
 public interface topicRepo extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {
```

Comment: Still giving the same error when I send a get request, It works fine if I do not use crud operations from the repository though.

Comment: ok try to extend JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository

Comment: still the same, not sure if I'm making a really stupid mistake

Comment: Adding `@Repository` to an interface adds absolutely nothing.

Comment: @M.Deinum if I remove Repository annotaion from my project it doesn't work so tell us why it adds absolutely nothing instead of mark my answer as not useful !

Comment: Because Spring Data doesn't use the `@Repository` annotation to detect repositories. It uses different means, so adding that annotation to a Spring Data interface driven repository adds nothing. Interfaces are even ignored when the component-scanning detects them as you cannot create an instance of an interface.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember well you still have to create the functions/methods in the @Repository file that you need as below example from [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/). Also try to keep the syntax for classes to start with UpperCase letter TopicRepo instead of topicRepo and objects with lower case topicReport instead of TopicRepo:

```
@Autowired
TopicRepo topicReport
```

and finally your repo interface:

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepo extends CrudRepository<Topic, Long> {

  List<Topic> findAll();

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure since the findAll() method comes from the Crud repo, the creation isn't necessary. But I tried both still giving the same Null pointer exception

Comment: `findAll` is part of `CrudRepository` 's default methods, so no you don't need to add them.